# In phonegap date tag is working fine in all devices except LG Optimus (android 4.2 ver)

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am using date tag for calendar picker in phonegap mobile application. it is working absolutely fine in all mobile devices except LG Optimus (android 4.2 ver). sorry if I am unable to explain my question, I am new in phonegap and my communication is not so good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you the same android version on all devices?

Answer (score 1):

Android versions before 4.4 [doesn't support the date tag](http://caniuse.com/#search=date).

You must [check at runtime](http://modernizr.com/) if html5 input date is available: if not you need to load an alternative js datepicker. One good responsive datepicker is [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/).

Comment: thanks @lifeisfoo. I will check this and get back to you.